# letsencrypt ssl for nodejs on nginx on ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I have successfully deployed a nodejs app running on `localhost:8000` and has a redirect to port 80.

I also successfully generated .pem files and ssl cert using letsencrypt's `certbot`. All files are placed where they should be.

However when accessing the domain via https, it's not working.

Here's my nginx setup.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sample.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AE$';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The non http app is working when `ufw` is disabled, it doesn't otherwise.

1. `ufw enabled` = http and https not working
2. `ufw disabled` = http working but not https

[image]

Comment: Config looks fine to me. Can you describe "it is not working"? Any error message? Didn't you forget to open port 443 on your firewall, for example?

Comment: Hey @Pierre thanks for replying. There's no error really, the page loads fine in on-http and get the error "This site can't be reached" on https. Regarding the firewall, I assume we are talking about `ufw` here right? Currently, it is disabled, how will that affect the certificate? Thanks.

Comment: Clearly, this is probably nothing related to the certificate itself. Nginx would complain if the certificate was malformed or misplaced, and the browser would if the certificate was incorrect. What is the result of `netstat -an | grep 443`?

Comment: You mean the site loads fine on sample.com:8000 ? If it loads fine on sample.com, you have a problem with your ports. Did you reload nginx after making changes?

Comment: I see, there aren't any problems with the `nginx -t` so I guess certs are just fine. Heres what `netstat -an | grep 443` spits out. `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:443 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN` and `tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN`

Comment: @Pierre `sample.com:8000` no it's not working. What works is `10.10.10.xxx` and `sample.com` `port 8000` is being redirected to `port 80` via `iptables`

Comment: @Pierre also, when ufw is enabled, the app is not working, it's fine otherwise.

Comment: I don't get it. If it works with `ufw` disabled (you previous said it was), the problem is clearly there, isn't it? Doesn't a simple `sudo ufw allow https` solve the issue?

Comment: @Pierre Im sorry please see update on question

Comment: Just something else I don't understand. What does "port 8000 is being redirected to port 80 via iptables" mean?  This should be the job of the `proxy_pass` NGINX directive, isn't it?

Comment: Should I get rid of that? It was supposedly for the DNS setup. @Pierre

Comment: There's no point in doing an ip table redirect if you're using a proxy in nginx. And those ufw rules look redundant. Kill your ip table redirect and kill all your ufw rules. Start from there. If sample.com:8000 works, good. Proxy 443 to localhost:8000. If your https works, you're good. ufw deny all incoming. ufw allow ssh. ufw allow 80/tcp. ufw allow 443/tcp. Done. (and obv ufw allow all outgoing)

Comment: Thanks @Pierre I will do those. But how do you exactly proxy 443 to localhost:8000 in nginx. I guess Ill continue later, I lost connection to the remote.

Comment: This is the job of Nginx, with the `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`. You are with this line specifically asking Nging to request the page on port 8000 for you.